# run ansible playbook with sudo

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook and I want to run it with sudo. It is my ansible playbook:

#### site.yml

```
---
- name: Server
  hosts: node1
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - dbserver
```

When I run it I get this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml

PLAY [Server] ***************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [node1] => Missing sudo password

TASK: [dbserver | installing server] ****************************************** 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/robe/site.retry

node1                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Then I add the ansible sudo pass on site.yml:

```
---
- name: Server
  hosts: node1
  sudo_pass: ubuntu
  roles:
    - dbserver
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: sudo_pass is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook
```

Then my questions are:

- Do I have add to each tasks the ansible sudo_pass attribute?
- Is there any way to say sudo and sudo_pass in the playbook?

Answer (score 12):

`sudo_pass` is not something Ansible knows. If you need to enter a sudo password on node1, then you keep `sudo: yes` in the playbook, and you'll have to give Ansible the sudo password on the commandline when running your playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml -K
```

Note the `-K` parameter. It will then ask you for the sudo password before the playbook starts.

(the long version is --ask-sudo-pass by the way. I had to look that up)

Comment: It works but I don't want to set the password when I run the tasks. I need this because I want to automate my infrastructure. So if you have any tip about how to configure it??

Comment: @Robert I know I'm nine years late, but if you want your infrastructure to be automated, then why are you using a user who needs to type in their password to run commands using sudo? Configure your /etc/sudoers such that the ansible user, once authenticated via ssh key, doesn't have to type in passwords